# CanDeactivate guard has no access to functions of component it's guarding

Tags: angularjs, angular, navigation, angular-routing, angular2-directives

I am trying to use a CanActivate guard in angular2 to ask user to save changes.
I am using angular RC4

Boot.ts

```
bootstrap(App, [
...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
StorageService,
PortfolioNavigationGuard,
other...
```

Routes.ts

```
export const PortfolioRoutes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: 'portfolios', component: 'PortfolioListComponent' },
{ path: 'portfolios/:id', component: 'PortfolioModelComponent', canDeactivate: [PortfolioNavigationGuard] },
{ path: 'portfolios/:id/:action', component: 'PortfolioModelComponent', canDeactivate: [PortfolioNavigationGuard]  }
```

Guard

```
@Injectable()
```

`export class PortfolioNavigationGuard implements CanDeactivate<PortfolioDetailComponent> {`

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

canDeactivate(component: PortfolioDetailComponent) {

    component.canDeactivate();
    component.anyfunction() --- anyfunction is not a function

    return true;
}
```

The error

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: component.canDeactivate is not a function
```

The component

```
export class PortfolioDetailComponent {
canDeactivate() {
    console.log("WOW");
}
```

Why can't I call any functions on the component inside my guard?

Comment: AFAIK the component is only created after the guard resolves to `true`. I assume the `component` getter is the resolved component or the type of the component used to create it by the `<router-outlet>`.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes:

Switched the guard implementation to a different component ( same one I defined in the route config) :

```
export class PortfolioNavigationGuard implements CanDeactivate<PortfolioDetailComponent> {
```

to

```
export class PortfolioNavigationGuard implements CanDeactivate<PortfolioModelComponent> {
```

There are two things to note. The first component is not loaded through router outlet, while the second is. I was thinking that components that belong to another(used as tag in template) still can access the route data (You can subscribe to the route id change let's say in components that were brought using a selector and not a router outlet), however it seems that for the guard, the component that you are putting the guard on must be brought with router outlet.